# Strange behavior about request size limit in Abp web api

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, abp

In .Net Core Project, we could set global request size limit :

```
int sizeLimit = 200000;
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = sizeLimit;
});

services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = sizeLimit);
```

Then do more strictly request size limit by filter :

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestApiController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [RequestSizeLimit(100_000)]
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 100_000)]
    public bool Post(IFormFile file)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But, in the Abp Project, strange situations:
(whether a common web api controller or a dynamic web api controller)

upload a 150,000 bytes file

1. global limit: 200,000; filter limit: 100,000 => will pass (confuse, cause it should be rejected)
2. global limit: 100,000; filter limit: 200,000 => will pass
3. if upload a file beyond 200,000 bytes => will be rejected

Is that a bug or i miss something i should set in the project?

- ABP Framework version: abp.io v4.3.0
- Framework version: .Net 5

---

**======================== Renew 2022/04/10 ========================**
After setting log level i found warning logs even in happy case, uploading a very small size file.

```
2022-04-10 08:14:49.299 +08:00 [WRN] A request body size limit could not be applied. The IHttpRequestBodySizeFeature for the server is read-only.
2022-04-10 08:14:49.299 +08:00 [WRN] Unable to apply configured form options since the request form has already been read.
```

Comment: Please check your app logs.

Comment: hi @maliming, you can my case1. There aren't any error log, because flie is passed by filter. But it should be rejected. It's a weird behavior.

Comment: Please set the log level to see the logs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#log-level

Comment: @maliming thank you. I have found warning log and i will try to deal with it.

Comment: hi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71256014/strange-behavior-about-request-size-limit-in-abp-web-api#